# Insert INTO NOT EXISTS SQL access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, insert

I am trying to insert records from another table into a table in Access using sql.  I have pasted the statement below.  I want to insert the records that exist in ImportMetricsIDs01262015 but not in ShouldImportMetricsIDs.  It runs perfectly without any errors but it won't insert anything even when I physically add a new record.

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable ( [Formulary ID], [Market Segment] )
SELECT ImportMetricsIDs01262015.[Formulary ID], ImportMetricsIDs01262015.[Market Segment]
FROM ImportMetricsIDs01262015
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a correlation clause.  The subquery just checks whether or not the table is empty.  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable( [Formulary ID], [Market Segment] )
    SELECT im.[Formulary ID], im.[Market Segment]
    FROM ImportMetricsIDs01262015 as im
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable as sim
                      WHERE im.[Formulary ID] = sim.[Formulary ID] AND
                            im.[Market Segment] = sim.[Market Segment]
                     );
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate your `NOT Exist` query with the `ImportMetricsIDs01262015` table

This code is on the assumption that FormularyID is the key in both the tables.

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable (
    [Formulary ID]
    ,[Market Segment]
    )
SELECT ImportMetricsIDs01262015.[Formulary ID]
    ,ImportMetricsIDs01262015.[Market Segment]
FROM ImportMetricsIDs01262015
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable
        where ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable.[Formulary ID] = ImportMetricsIDs01262015.[Formulary ID]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "TOP" is necessary in access which is made bold and italic in the code

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable( [Formulary ID], [Market Segment] )
SELECT im.[Formulary ID], im.[Market Segment]
FROM ImportMetricsIDs01262015 as im
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
***TOP*** 1
                  FROM ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable as sim
                  WHERE im.[Formulary ID] = sim.[Formulary ID] AND
                        im.[Market Segment] = sim.[Market Segment]
                 );
```

Comment: Tested and works without TOP. If use TOP then need a field name or *: `SELECT TOP 1 *`.